# Проверить id пользователя VK и access_token

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, oauth2, token, соцсети

Я хочу авторизировать пользователя в VK в iOS/Android приложениях, а на C++ сервере удостовериться, что VK id от этого пользователя настоящий.
Чтобы проделать подобную операцию в FB нужно выполнить следующих [два запроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543882/verify-facebook-access-token-for-specific-app):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=my_access_token
https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=my_access_token
```

Первый вернет id пользователя, чей это токен, а второй - id приложения, который этот токен сгенерировал.

Кстати, полностью ли это верная схема для FB?

Для VK, в свою очередь, я нашел только первый запрос, который вернет id пользователя, чей это токен:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=my_access_token
```

Но не могу найти запрос, который вернет id приложения, который этот токен сгенерировал.

Итак, как проверить настоящий ли VK id пользователя передан на сервер с помощью VK API?

Comment: Ты можешь сделать цифровую подпись для данных, передаваемых от приложения серверу.

Comment: @Profesor08, fb вход будет реализован с помощью указанных двух запросов, поэтому отдельно для vk делать такую схему не очень хочется. Нужно более унифицированное решение, поэтому надеюсь найти аналог этим двум запросам в vk api.

Comment: Не вижу проблемы. Тебе в любом случае надо делать какой-то интерфейс, который позволит авторизовывать пользователей, который уже будет заниматься частными случаями по отдельности вроде вк, фб и тд.

Comment: Для Facebook проще использовать appsecret_proof (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof), его можно передавать с любым методом. Для ВК удалось решить проблему?

Comment: @AlekDepler спасибо, посмотрю. Я тогда другими вещами занялся, недавно решил с саппортом пообщаться на эту тему, в итоге они и сами не уверены в некоторых деталях, буду держать здесь в курсе.

Answer (score 1):

Метод apps.get без передачи id приложения вернёт id приложения, которое сгенерировало токен

https://api.vk.com/method/apps.get?access_token=my_access_token